# what will happen if two nodes with same name claiming same address in j1939?

Tags: can-bus, j1939

If two nodes with same name claiming same address in j1939 what will happen in this situation? will any one of node will claim address or error will occour ?

Comment: I don't think that's allowed!

Comment: What do you mean by same name? could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

My copy of the specification is dated, but I'm sure this rule hasn't changed since 2003 (SAE J1939-81):

"Manufacturers of ECUs and integrators of networks must assure that the NAMEs of all CAs intended to
transmit on a particular network are unique."

Of course, that being said, it is of course possible to put devices with the same NAME on the 
same set of wires, either through ignorance or malicious intent.

I personally haven't played with it, but in theory, if your device has the exact same NAME as another,
your address claim will exactly overlap the other,  neither would be aware of the other's presence,
the message would go through successfully, and each device will assume it is the one that sent it.

I may be wrong, but I think the only thing odd an CA might see is message coming in from an address
it thought it had claimed, a problem which it may not even be checking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the network standpoint, there is no way to distinguish that the nodes are different since they are identifying themselves as the same entity. What would happen is that the first requests will be addressed, and the second request will be ignored. In other words, this is race condition because only one message is processed at a time in the datalink. By the time the second node tries to claim the same address, the address table is already occupied and the late request node won't be able to get the notification that the address was assigned to it. Remember that each node has its own internal states/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

J1939-81 says

> "Repeated Collisions Occur, devices go BUS OFF CAs should retry using
> a Pseudo-random delay before attempting to reclaim and then revert to
> Figures 2 and 3."